# Making Argument Diagrams in LaTex

Tags: diagrams, logic

I am trying to do my homework for Logic lesson in LaTex and I need to make Argument Diagrams. I have no idea how to make these in LaTex. All I think is doing it manually with TikzImage.

Below are some examples for Argument Diagrams. (From our textbook “Schaum’s outline Logic 2nd Edition”)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

After searching on the internet I saw people doing Argument Diagrams with tikzcd. This is an example of something I did by copying other people's work.

```
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5em,column sep=0.3em]
                {1} \arrow{d} \& {} \& {} \& {} \& {} \& {} \& {}  \\
                {2} \& {+} \& {3} \& {+}\arrow{d} \& {4} \& {+} \& {5}  \\
                {} \& {} \& {} \& {6} \& {} \& {} \& {}  \\
            \end{tikzcd}
        \end{center}
```

And here is the image of the output:
[image]

However, I want to add a horizontal line under the second row.

[image]

I couldn’t find any way to do it. Are you guys familiar with how to do such a thing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Isn’t it the purpose of homework to do them yourself? What you try so far? Where you stuck in your efforts?

Comment: I don't think you really *need* Ti*k*Z to do that but it can be done with it, with simple nodes and edges. Come back with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you tried.

Comment: @Zarko Actually my purpose for my homework is to do my diagrams not to do LaTex. I also could make these pdf’s by handwriting and scanning the diagrams, however, since I am trying to learn LaTex I wanted to make a fresh start by trying to do homeworks via LaTex.

Comment: Hi, just try to check so key words in Google :   tikz  arrows  "tikz tree with arrows" and so on and You will find Your solution be shure

Comment: I edited your question adding what you wrote in your (not an) answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
   \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={name=mymatr},row sep=1.5em,column sep=0.3em, ampersand replacement=\&, execute at end picture={\draw (mymatr-2-1.south west) -- (mymatr-2-7.south east);}]
            {1} \arrow{d} \& {} \& {} \& {} \& {} \& {} \& {}  \\
            {2} \& {+} \& {3} \& {+}\arrow{d} \& {4} \& {+} \& {5}  \\
            {} \& {} \& {} \& {6} \& {} \& {} \& {}  \\
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One possibilities is use of pure `tikz`.

For starting point may serve this (no very simple) example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes.multipart,
                }
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 5mm and 0mm,
      arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, semithick},
HMPN/.style args = {#1/#2}{%
                    rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
                    rectangle split horizontal,
                    inner ysep=1pt, outer ysep=1pt,
                    node contents={#1\nodepart{two}\kern-1.4pt+\kern-1.4pt\nodepart{three}#2},
                    path picture={\draw (\ppbb.south west) -- (\ppbb.south east);}},
                    ]
\node (a) [HMPN=3/4];   % 3 + 4
\node (b) [HMPN=1/2, below left = of a.two split south]; % 1 + 2
    \draw[arr] (a.south) -- (b.three north);
\node (c) [below=of b] {5};
    \draw[arr] (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hello after searching in the internet I saw people doing Argument Diagrams with tikzcd. This is example of something I did by copying other peoples work.

```
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5em,column sep=0.3em]
                {1} \arrow{d} \& {} \& {} \& {} \& {} \& {} \& {}  \\
                {2} \& {+} \& {3} \& {+}\arrow{d} \& {4} \& {+} \& {5}  \\
                {} \& {} \& {} \& {6} \& {} \& {} \& {}  \\
            \end{tikzcd}
        \end{center}
```

And here is the image of the output:
[image]

However I want to add a horizontal line under second row.

[image]

I couldn’t find anyway to do it. Are you guys familiar with how to do such a thing.

Thanks

Comment: Bravo! Better and simpler than mine solution! +1

Comment: @Zarko but this is not an answer...

Comment: @Atahan I answered starting from this post, please look at my answer.

Comment: @CarLaTex, it is written as answer. It is good one and can be accepted as such (regardless that is copy of some solution, as OP said) :-)

Comment: @Zarko No, read it all, it is a question

Comment: @CarLaTeX, ah, seems that I made a mess :-(. Sorry, and +1 for your answer :-)

Comment: @Zarko Don't worry I have already edited the question to include this "answer".